# With HtmlAgilityPack, verify that element on webpage exists

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, dom

Let's say I'm on http://google.com, and I want to verify that there is an element with `id="hplogo"` that exists on the page (which there is, it's the Google logo).

I want to use HtmlAgilityPack, so I write something like this:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("http://google.com");
    var foo = (from bar in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
               where bar.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "hplogo"
               select bar).FirstOrDefault();
    if (foo == null)
    {
        HasSucceeded = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("not there");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it's there");
    }
    return HasSucceeded;
}
```

Which should return the "it's there" message because it is there.  But it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I've only been coding with Visual Studio for like 2 weeks so I'm still new to how it all works.  But I have been using them, I just don't know how to interpret the information it gives me.

EDIT:  Okay comment deleted classic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `LoadHtml(html)` loads string, which contain html content for parsing. This is not url of resource to load. So you are loading string `"http://google.com"` and trying to find logo in it. Which of course gives you *not there* result.

You can use `WebClient` to download resource content:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```